# Recursive add stars between Characters

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive method to add stars between characters in a character arraylist. I am also trying to avoid hard coding in the method. Here is my attempt with the test code and desired output. I am trying to use a list iterator but I am wondering if there is a better way?

```
public static String addStars(List<Character> str) {
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }

    else {

        char hold = '*';

        str.listIterator(1).add(hold);

        str.listIterator(3).add(hold);

    }

    return str.get(0) + addStars(str.subList(2, str.size()));
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Character> example = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'b',  'c'));
    System.out.println(example); // [a, b, c]
    System.out.println(addStars(example)); // a*b*c
    System.out.println(example); // [a, *, b, *, c]
}
```

}

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: My program is not outputting what I want it to. I am wondering if there is a more practical solution.

Comment: Do you want to modify the existing list? Or return a new list? In general, modifying variables is a dangerous operation.

Comment: The existing list would be preffered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
public class Whatever {
    private final static char hold = '*';

    public static String addStars(List<Character> str) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        } else if (str.size() < 2) {
            //Don't add star after last character
            return "" + str.get(0);
        }

        //Add only one star per iteration
        str.listIterator(1).add(hold);
        List<Character> sublist = str.subList(2, str.size());
        return "" + str.get(0) + hold + addStars(sublist);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Character> example = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c'));
        System.out.println(example); // [a, b, c]
        System.out.println(addStars(example)); // a*b*c
        System.out.println(example); // [a, *, b, *, c]
    }
}
```

Comment: [a, b, c]
139140c
[a, b, c] is what my editor put out

Comment: I fixed that, try now.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
public static void addStars(int offset, List<Character> str) {
    if (offset < str.size()) {
        str.add(offset, '*');
        addStars(offset + 2, str);
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<Character> example = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'b',  'c'));
    System.out.println(example); // [a, b, c]
    addStars(1, example);
    System.out.println(example); // [a, *, b, *, c]
}
```

}

Comment: Could it be done with a helper method as I would prefer not to change the method return type or test code?

Comment: When using recursion you have to without a return type most of the time because it would create an object on the heap for every recursive call which you want to avoid. Recursion is implemented using the stack.
No problem though if you return an existing object like List<Character> str

Comment: I am only wondering due to this method being from a superclass which is also implemented in other classes I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void addStars() {
    ArrayList<Character> example = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c'));
    List<Character> modList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    //There is where the magic happens.
    char CHAR_TO_ADD = '*';

    //Interating over the characters
    for (char temp : example) {
        modList.add(CHAR_TO_ADD);
        modList.add(temp);

    }

    for (char temp : modList) {
        System.out.print(temp + " ");
    }
}
```

I think you are looking for something like this. 
I have included a for each loose because they are easier when dealing with lists. If you want to trim the last character at the end, so that way you have a star right before each character. All if you have to do is swap staredList.add(temp) and staredList.add(CHAR_TO_ADD).

Another option could be using a for loop that way you are more in control of the position of the list that you are looking at and managing.

Comment: I am trying to do this with recursion to better understand arraylists with recursion. I also am not trying to modify the method return type as this method is from a superclass. Would a helper method be better?

Answer (score 0):

Do you insist on recursion? The problem is that you are altering the original list and the last line `addStars(str.subList(2, str.size()))` is creating the sublist from longer list each time, so your recursion never ends. If you want to follow this approach you should introduce some index and increment each time.

Comment: I am trying to better understand recursion with arraylists. I know that this could be done much easier with loops.